# Is it possible for me to make my discord bot send messages based on a website?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord.js bot where it can send a message based on a website, like on https://whereisxur.com, when I send a command like !xur, it'll send where is the location of xur, etc...
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can! You can use a process called [scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). Like the other answer states, you're going to want to make HTTP requests. You can use node's http module to do this with JavaScript. [Here's some documentation on http](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-http-module). You'll probably want to get the HTML and use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to get the info you want. Good luck!

**Edit:**

In case you wanted one, [here's a beginner's tutorial](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-javascript/) to start you off :)

**Edit 2:**

Regex is hard, so I figured I'd do it for you. Here's what I would use:

```js
// works for me so far
/(?<=\>Xûr is )(.*?)(?=\<)/g // currently returns "at the Tower in the Hangar"
```

Comment: I'll try this and I'll tell you the result, thanks for replying!

Comment: hey, can you explain what /(?<=\>Xûr is )(.*?)(?=\<)/g do?

Comment: @Ekitai `/(?<=\>Xûr is )(.*?)(?=\<)/g` is known as a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). A regex in short allows you to find something within a string or match what a string is trying to say. An example of this could if making sure an email address exists by checking that it includes the `@` symbol and a `.` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible.
create a discord bot using your preferred language , python in my personal opinion.
use a server which hold the code of your discord bot and use restfull api to send request to your server , HTTP request basically.

Comment: I'll try this and I'll tell you the result, thanks for replying!